# CSS add remove border on class toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently ran into an issue when adding or removing a border based on a adding or removing a class. I have fixed the issue, but I am not satisfied with the solution.

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydzquus5/8/) illustrating the problem. Even with transitions on both classes, the border will transition in correctly, but will transition out abruptly.

**EDIT**: The issue is fixed by setting a border property with the same attributes. Setting a "border: 0px solid red;" on .boxy fixes it, but setting just "border: 0px;" does not.

Here is the *working* jsfiddle code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="boxy"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.boxy {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: black;
   border: 0px solid red;
   -webkit-transition: border 300ms linear 0s;
   -moz-transition: border 300ms linear 0s;
   -o-transition: border 300ms linear 0s;
   transition: border 300ms linear 0s;
}

.selected {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.boxy').click(function(event){
    $('.boxy').toggleClass('selected');
})
```

Comment: for me transition IN and OUT works fine. Can't see a problem there

Comment: Are you referring to the jsfiddle? I think there may have been a previous version of it in my post (from when I used the fix described in the OP). I changed it. Could you verify that it still does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the correct border on `.boxy` and set it's width to `0px`.

Like this `border: 0px solid red;`, so you will apply the `transition` between `0px` and `10px`

**Explanation**

> It enables you to define the transition between two states of an element.
>
> ---
>
> [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

So in your case, you've to define the initial state of the border. (`border: 0px solid red`)

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwachtler/zumsbtw4/)**

Comment: Thank you. This is the fix I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to add the transition on both classes, try this:

```
.boxy {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: border 300ms linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: border 300ms linear 0s;
    -o-transition: border 300ms linear 0s;
    transition: border 300ms linear 0s;
}

.selected {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

**EDIT**: With your new JSFiddle you need this:

```
.boxy{
   border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but could you explain why? I thought the transitions needed to be defined both when switching to the class and switching back?

Comment: Because you need the transition in the boxy element, independently of the other class

Comment: @PeterBenavides use your dev tools to see what happens to the css rules that are applied to your div. Once you click and "selected" class is removed all the css about "selected" is gone. The transition happens because you have already defined it to your "boxy" class

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for your response. I understand now.

Comment: @antithesis answer is better than mine! I also had some troubles when I started using css transitions! I hope we help you!